# How to ignore user input until minimum 2 digits/chars entered

Tags: jquery

https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox

I am using this code base to allow autocomplete in my MVC app.  It works great in Chrome but in IE it will sometimes sit and churn after user enters a single character or digit, then erase the input box and return nothing.  I have discovered it seems to do this only when the returned dataset is huge, it seems IE cant handle it.

I am thinking I can fix this by forcing the user to enter at least 2 digits/char before beginging the search but I cant find the place in the script to make that change (I'm still kinda new to JS).

I'm thinking of doing something like this, but not sure where to put it:

```
var el = $('.combobox').combobox();

el.on('change', function(e){

  var value = $("#seed").val();

  var len = value.length;

  console.log("value is " + value + ' ' + " length is: " + len);

  if(len < 2) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
})
```

Comment: Please add the current code that launches the search.

Comment: plz provide search code

Comment: Your process flow will be : 1. type in something in $('#seed') 2: if the length of $('#seed') is greater than two, then query data out from the server; 3: apply new data to $('.combobox'), right?

Comment: If so, the code will be: $('#seed').on('change', function(e){if($(this).val().length>2){$('.combobox').trigger('loadData');} });

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try it using model binding, it will give you server/client side validation.
I am describing how you could solve it with a .NET example:

```
[StringLength(60, MinimumLength = 2)]        
public string Title {get;set;}
```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/complex-data-model

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix my particular situation.  I was never able to find an error when using in IE, but I noticed that when the select list was particularly long, the combobox would stop working.  The fix I cam up was to add minimum length feature to teh script so the user has to put atleast 2 numbers in the input before the search script fires.

In the bootstrap-combobox script I changed this:

```
  , lookup: function (event) {
      this.query = this.$element.val();
      return this.process(this.source);
    }
```

to this:

```
  , lookup: function (event) {
      this.query = this.$element.val();

      if (this.query.length > 1) {
          return this.process(this.source);
      }
    }
```